# Paypal Express checkout implementation

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Actually I'm trying to set express checkout in my personal site but I'm not sure if I'm doing it on the right way. Here's my simple HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PaypalTest</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method=post action=https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp>
        <input type=hidden name=USER value=mySandBoxAccount>
        <input type=hidden name=PWD value=myPWD>
        <input type=hidden name=SIGNATURE value=mySignature>
        <input type=hidden name=VERSION value=204>
        <input type=hidden name=PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION value=Sale>
        <input name=PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT value=19.95>
        <input type=hidden name=RETURNURL value=http://localhost:8080/PaypalTest/confirm.html>
        <input type=hidden name=CANCELURL value=http://localhost:8080/PaypalTest/cancel.html>
        <input type=submit name=METHOD value=SetExpressCheckout>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I press submit button, the sandbox URL shows me a token and success message but RETURNURL is not working because nothing happens in this step, just I have sandbox page with some information.

Comment: You need to build actual HTTP requests with cURL using a language like PHP or anything else you're comfortable with.  If you want to stick with basic HTML form buttons you'll have to use PayPal Payments Standard instead of Express Checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement PayPal Express Checkout refer sample codes at "demo.paypal.com", with Simple HTML you can set PayPal Standard only.

User name, password & signature are available in ur PayPal profile:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/